# How to access .db file from android device using phonegap 1.5.0

Tags: cordova

I'm working on phonegap 1.5.0. Our project needs to access the database. In eclipse it is stored in data/data/packagename/app_database/file_0/0000000000001.db but while running the program on android device we are unable to find this database.

And do we require rooted android device to access the database?
Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer following link.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

Answer (score 0):

I have modified Cordova (https://github.com/Coder-Nasir/incubator-cordova-android) in such a way that it will create the database in Android's Default location which is `/data/data/package-name/databases/`

By just this simple command:

```
window.openDatabase("something", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 0);
```

You will get your desired something.db in the above mentioned location..

Answer (score 0):

To access the db, you can use SQLitePlugin via the below link and can fire the queries:-
https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin